# Excel difference between two columns

Tags: excel

I have this question that puzzles me. Two columns of unique text entries in a worksheet all having a number next to each of them.
How can I compare the values for each pair of text and find the ones where the associated numbers are NOT the same. 
Not even sure how the output would be. Maybe using Conditional Formatting highlighting the value in the first column where the match in the second one is different???
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot and some sample data (input) with a mock-up of the desired outcome?

Comment: Hi Ralph. Thanks for your help. I'm not very familiar with StackOverflow interface. I wouldn't know how to load an image. But let's say that in my set of data I have:

First Set
ABC-1
DEF-6

and Second Set
ABC-8
DEF-6

"Note the hyphen is not in the data I just put it there myself"

If I can get a TRUE that for the ABC in Set 1 since it differs from the one in Set 2 then I could use Conditional Formatting to highlight the value 1 in Red for instance. The user would be happy to accept that since this would indicate that there is a discrepancy with Set 2 for item ABC. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's have some sample table.

```
+-----+---+-------+---+------------------------------------+
| A   | B | C     | D | =VLOOKUP(C1;ALL_VALUES;2;FALSE)=D1 |
+-----+---+-------+---+------------------------------------+
| abc | 1 | fasfa | 4 | #N/A                               |
+-----+---+-------+---+------------------------------------+
| aa  | 2 | abc   | 1 | TRUE                               |
+-----+---+-------+---+------------------------------------+
| dd  | 3 | dd    | 2 | FALSE                              |
+-----+---+-------+---+------------------------------------+
```

Where ALL_VALUES is named range of you table (here A1:D3). Formula returns TRUE when match is found, else it return False Or #N/A(You can transform #N/A by `IfError` function). Then you can filter the result in table based on this or you conditional formatting... Depends on what suits you better ;)